# Why mysql table raw ID is not showing serially?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

[image: Snapshot 1]

[image: Snapshot 2]

Does anyone answer me why MySQL table raw id not serially?

Comment: If you simply want it sorted in phpmyadmin why dont you click on the 'id' column head and phpmyadmin will sort it for you? Otherwise, you can always run an order by yourself

Comment: I know if I click the id, it will sort serially but I would like to see the id will be sorting serially by default. The problem is when export, the id sorting as a shuffle.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will try to give you the results as quick as it can, based on your query.

If you didn't tell MySQL to sort on any field, MySQL will probably pick the order in which it's sorted on the disk.

Records in mysql aren't always stored in order on disk. An example where they might go out of order is if you delete a record in the middle of the table. The next record might (for space saving reasons) be inserted in the position where you deleted a record earlier.

Don't worry about this. This is normal. If you create an application that uses MySQL, make sure you include `ORDER BY id` at the end of your query to get your predictable order.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use an `ORDER BY` clause to make your desired order explicit, the query results are up to the implementation. That means MySQL gets to choose the order if you don't.

In the case of MyISAM tables, the default order is the order rows are stored in the table, which can get mixed up over time as rows are added and deleted. New rows may fit into gaps left by deleted rows, even if that makes them stored "out of order".

In the case of InnoDB tables, the default order is by the index used to read the rows. This is often the primary key, but it might not be. It depends on your table definition and the SQL query you use to read the rows.

Just use `ORDER BY` if you want the rows ordered by a specific column.